# Radiation pressure thermodynamic paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, thermal-radiation

Could the radiation pressure of a black body (theoretically) perform work on the perfectly reflecting apparatus in the figure below? Assume that the block does not hinder the passage of light through the aperture.

[image]

(The source of the radiation is to the left of the block.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is more flux coming into the open end of the tube than the thermal radiation in the closed part of the piston then yes.

Radiation pressure doing work is perfectly feasible eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail

Comment: A perfect reflector has 0 emissivity, so you must be referring to the radiation trapped during construction. I do not understand where your answer addresses the apparent thermodynamics problem.

Comment: @Velox You appear to be making this harder than it needs to be. Martin's answer is complete. You *could* analyze it in terms of a photon gas, but that would be harder and therefore only interesting as an exercise.